# What is meant by register-impaired architecture

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, architecture, cpu-architecture

I am reading Robert Love's linux kernel development book. In that, book he is mentioning about register-impaired architecture. I don't know what is register-impaired architecture. Kindly explain me, if anyone knows about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: xyz-impaired person is somebody that cannot do xyz or does not have enough of xyz .... so i am guessing that register-impaired device does not have enough registers ... such device would have to copy data into and out of general memory, usually by way of a stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context can make it somewhat clearer (emphasis mine):

> This allowed *architectures with few registers, such as x86*, to
>   calculate the location of the process descriptor via the stack pointer
>   without using an extra register to store the location.With the process
>   descriptor now dynamically created via the slab allocator, a new
>   structure, `struct thread_info`, was created that again lives at the
>   bottom of the stack (for stacks that grow down) and at the top of the
>   stack (for stacks that grow up).<sup>3</sup>
>
> <sup>3</sup> Register-impaired architectures were not the only reason
>   for creating `struct thread_info`.

The author is just joking about the architectures like x86 having few registers. "X-impaired" ~ X is diminished compared to others. (For example, "financially impaired" = does not have enough money.)

Comment: If you want yo give some context: that was written at the time of 32bit x86 -- x86-64 is no longer register impaired, and the extra registers were a big drive for its adoption, probably more than the direct access to a 64bit address space.

Comment: Yes, that's often mentioned as one of the plus points of x86-64 in the recent mess of Ubuntu removing support for 32-bit x86.